# How can I reduce the lines of this JS code to make it shorter and more efficient?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I'm new to JavaScript so I'm currently working through MDN's official 2D Breakout Game tutorial and changing stuff around on my own to better understand how things work. As part of my changes in the 6th Step of the tutorial (called "Build the brick field"), I wrote the following code that works exactly how I want it to, but I feel I could make this code shorter in a way, and I don't know how.

```
function drawBricks() {
    for (c = 0; c < bricksColCount - 3; c++) {
        for (r = 0; r < bricksRowCount-1; r++) {
            setRowsCol();
        }
    }

    for (c = 2; c < bricksColCount - 2; c++) {
        for (r = 0; r < bricksRowCount - 4; r++) {
            setRowsCol();
        }
    }

    for (c = 3; c < bricksColCount; c++) {
        for (r = 0; r < bricksRowCount; r++) {
            setRowsCol();
        }
    }
}
```

The `setRowsCol()` function I'm referring to in this code is written like this:

```
function setRowsCol() {
    bricks[c][r].x = bricksOffsetLeft + (c * (bricksWidth + bricksPadding));
    bricks[c][r].y = bricksOffsetTop + (r * (bricksHeight + bricksPadding));
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(bricks[c][r].x, bricks[c][r].y, bricksWidth, bricksHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

Any idea to reduce the lines and make the code shorter without changing the way it works? Since I'm new to JavaScript, I want to make sure I apply proper techniques.

Comment: This question is more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: not to mention that using global variables instead of parameters make it a hard job to debug, who knows when and where c & r might change, you are not making it very easy for the future you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked how to make the code shorter and more efficient, but I think there are more important things that you should address.

#### Write correct, readable code

The for-loops over the columns only work when `bricksColumnCount` is 5. To see why, try running the code in your head with `bricksColumnCount` equal to 10. You'll notice that some columns get drawn multiple times.

As a first step, I would forget about `bricksColumnCount` and explicitly use five columns:

```
function drawBricks() {
    // columns 0 and 1 each have (bricksRowCount - 1) bricks
    for (c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
        for (r = 0; r < bricksRowCount - 1; r++) {
            setRowsCol();
        }
    }

    // column 2 has (bricksRowCount - 4) bricks
    for (c = 2; c < 3; c++) {
        for (r = 0; r < bricksRowCount - 4; r++) {
            setRowsCol();
        }
    }

    // columns 3 and 4 each have bricksRowCount bricks
    for (c = 3; c < 5; c++) {
        for (r = 0; r < bricksRowCount; r++) {
            setRowsCol();
        }
    }
}
```

To generalise the code so that it works with arbitrary column counts, you need to decide how you want to partition the columns and write it as a formula involving `bricksColumnCount`. The original code in the question is a step in that direction, but isn't quite right.

#### Prefer function parameters to global variables

The behaviour of the function `setRowsCol` is controlled by the global variables `c` and `r`, which the calling code needs to set. This kind of programming style is very fragile. See http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad for some of the reasons.

The alternative is to use function parameters. See the [MDN Guide to Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) for an introduction.

You have already seen how values are passed to a function during a function call:

```
ctx.rect(bricks[c][r].x, bricks[c][r].y, bricksWidth, bricksHeight);
```

The function `ctx.rect` needs to know the location and dimensions of the rectangle to draw, and they are passed in by writing them inside the parentheses of the function call.

To declare that `setRowsCol` takes two parameters, change the declaration to the following:

```
function setRowsCol(c, r) {
    // the body remains the same
}
```

The calls to `setRowsCol` in `drawBricks` need to be updated so they look like this:

```
setRowsCol(c, r);
```

The order of the values in the call has to match the order of the parameters in the function declaration, but the names don't need to match. In fact, any expression can be used in a function call:

```
setRowsCol(1, 4);
```

This calls `setRowsCol`, and inside the body of `setRowsCol`, `c` will have the value 1 and `r` will have the value 4.

With these changes, the variables `c` and `r` don't need to be global any more so you should declare them as local variables in `drawBricks`:

```
function drawBricks() {
    var c;
    var r;

    // columns 0 and 1 each have (bricksRowCount - 1) bricks
    for (c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
        for (r = 0; r < bricksRowCount - 1; r++) {
            setRowsCol(c, r);
        }
    }

    // etc.
}
```

#### Don't worry about efficiency at this stage

If you've written a program that takes more than three seconds to run and you want to make it run faster, that's when you need to improve its efficiency. But for now, efficiency should be very low on your priority list.

Comment: Wow, I think I'm starting to really get this... Thanks a lot for the excellent insight. I'm going to read in detail the links you shared as well.

Comment: Now that's what I call a great explanation (could rather be for codereview though), but good work :)

Answer (score 5):

The number of lines of code does not directly correlate to how fast your code runs. Certain operations are more expensive than others.

In your example, the canvas operations are by far the most expensive. Your goal should be to improve speed by reducing the number of canvas operations.

I see that you are invoking `setRowsCol()` in loops and inside `setRowsCol()` you execute `beginPath()` and `closePath()`. Because you only need to execute `beginPath()` once you **start** drawing and `closePath()` once you're **done** drawing, it would be a good idea to take those two lines out of the looped function. Additionally, the `fillStyle` need only be set once and `fill()` need only be executed once. They can also be removed from the `setRowsCol()` function.  You could write it as such:

```
function setRowsCol() {
    bricks[c][r].x = bricksOffsetLeft + (c*(bricksWidth + bricksPadding));
    bricks[c][r].y = bricksOffsetTop + (r*(bricksHeight + bricksPadding));
    ctx.rect(bricks[c][r].x, bricks[c][r].y, bricksWidth, bricksHeight);
}

function drawBricks(){
    for(c = 0; c < bricksColCount-3; c++) {
        for(r = 0; r < bricksRowCount-1; r++) {
            setRowsCol();
        }
    }

    for(c = 2; c < bricksColCount-2; c++) {
        for(r = 0; r < bricksRowCount-4; r++) {
            setRowsCol();
        }
    }

    for(c = 3; c < bricksColCount; c++) {
        for(r = 0; r < bricksRowCount; r++) {
            setRowsCol();
        }
    }

}

var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
drawBricks();
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

The code could be better (e.g., not relying on global scope variables), but the idea is that you've moved some expensive canvas operations outside of looping code.

Comment: I'd say 'efficient' could mean all kind of things - maintainable, readable, compact - and not necessarily 'fast'. Your statement is still very valid, though.

Comment: I've always understood 'efficient' to refer to performance so I answered his question with regard to improving performance. I think it's a fair understanding of the word 'efficient'. In Nicholas Zakas' book `Even Faster Websites` he has a whole chapter titled `Writing Efficient JavaScript`. I wouldn't interpret 'efficient' to refer to maintainable, readable and compact.

Comment: Thanks for the tweaks and for making this much clearer Elliot! I wanted to paste my latest changes (I made some tweaks using your logic), but looks like it's too long for me to paste the new code here as a comment. Anyway, you really helped!

Comment: @ElliotB: The OP is clearly new to programming. You have to use your common sense and realise that efficiency is not important at all at this stage. There are much more important lessons that need to be taught, such as to use function parameters instead of global variables and to write correct, readable code (specifically, the for-loops are very fragile and in fact column 3 will be drawn twice).

Comment: @tom What do you recommend, please? Yes, I'm new so I'm really open to good advice to enhance my code in every possible way.

Comment: @tom StackOverflow is about asking specific questions and receiving specific answers. It's a QA site. It is not a wide-ranging open forum for teaching, as you say, 'all important lessons'. The OP asked a (relatively) specific question and I provided a specific answer. While I noted the OP's improper use of global variables in my answer, this is not the appropriate place to provide a full explanation of that. That's a different question that requires a different answer.

Comment: @ElliotB. On the subject of efficiency: The complexity of the original code is linear in the number of calls to `setRowsCol`. Your suggestion of moving `beginPath()` and `closePath()` outside makes the complexity quadratic (!). With your change, every call to `setRowsCol` appends a rectangle to the current path and calls `fill()`. Calling [fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fill) without arguments fills the ever-growing current path, hence the quadratic behaviour. The solution is to also move `ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";` and `ctx.fill();` outside.

Comment: @tom Surely you understand that complexity is not equivalent to efficiency? Half of your comment is irrelevant to the point of my answer. Your observation that his code is more efficient with `ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";` and `ctx.fill();` outside the function is correct. I've updated my answer for completeness.

Comment: @ElliotB. I modified the scripts to draw a 100 by 100 grid of bricks. Here is the [code from the question](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRBrNy?editors=1011) and here is [your first version](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZQxoj?editors=1011). On my machine, the original takes 40ms while your version takes more than 4 seconds and is killed. I am not going to do a micro-benchmark with the 5-column grid, because on that both versions are so fast that efficiency is not a concern.

Comment: @ElliotB. So in conclusion, when the grid is big enough for efficiency to be a concern, the original code from the question is orders of magnitude faster than your first version (without my correction).

Comment: @tom It's certainly a good thing that I already updated my answer thereby rendering your benchmark result irrelevant. Wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 1):

```
function drawBricks() {
    function loop(startCol, endColOffset, endRowOffset) {
        for (c = startCol; c < bricksColCount + endColOffset; c++) {
            for (r = 0; r < bricksRowCount + endRowOffset; r++) {
                setRowsCol();
            }
        }
    }

    loop(0, -3, -1);
    loop(2, -2, -4);
    loop(3, 0, 0);
}
```